# terraform wont download plugin without sudo

Tags: macos, terraform

I am trying to run the terraform code and running the terraform init but I am running into issues.
As you can see, when I run with sudo, it has no issues, but without it, it has. I am using mac os Mojave terraform 0.12. I checked the folder permissions and it is just fine. 
 once I run sudo terraform init, the other commands don't need the sudo command.

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...

Registry service unreachable.

This may indicate a network issue, or an issue with the requested Terraform Registry.


Registry service unreachable.

This may indicate a network issue, or an issue with the requested Terraform Registry.


Error: registry service is unreachable, check https://status.hashicorp.com/ for status updates



Error: registry service is unreachable, check https://status.hashicorp.com/ for status updates


C02Z1BCSLVCG:blue-deployment shakyas$ sudo terraform init
Password:

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...
- Downloading plugin for provider "aws" (hashicorp/aws) 2.42.0...
- Downloading plugin for provider "template" (hashicorp/template) 2.1.2...

The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
so the latest version was installed.

To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, it is recommended to add version = "..." constraints to the
corresponding provider blocks in configuration, with the constraint strings
suggested below.

* provider.aws: version = "~> 2.42"
* provider.template: version = "~> 2.1"

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy between your machine and the internet?

Comment: yes, I do. could that be the reason? if so, how do i fix it? i tried reaching the url using curl without sudo, and it works fine

Comment: How have you set your proxy configuration up? At a glance it looks like the root user has the proxy configured properly for Terraform but not your normal user. You should just do whatever you've done for the root user to your normal user to fix this. I'd start with checking the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable.

Comment: I setup the proxy to my user, by setting it up in ~/bashrc_profile for my user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I resolved it with removing a lot of certificates in my macOS Keychain.

It sound weird and I still don't understand why it works, but it works for others people too : https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/error-when-running-terraform-init/3135/6